# Scope of variables in python parallel execution

Tags: python

My issue is summarized with a simple code as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import numpy as np
h =  np.ones(3)
def func(i):
    global h
    h[i] = h[i]+i
    print(h[i])
print(h)
Parallel(n_jobs=3)(delayed(func)(i) for i in range(3))
print(h)
```

The output is:

```
[ 1.  1.  1.]
1.0
2.0
3.0
[ 1.  1.  1.]
```

However, I would like the `h` values to be modified as they are modified inside the loop. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I tried the answer `backend="threading"` suggested by `L_S`. It served the purpose. However, the code behaves in a serial manner. The loop was started with 3 n_jobs and I could see only one python running on doing `top`, whereas there are 3 python executables running without specifying `backend="threading"`.

Answer (score 0):

> By default Parallel uses the Python multiprocessing module to fork separate Python worker processes to execute tasks concurrently on separate CPUs.

So, You need to pass `backend="threading"`

```
Parallel(n_jobs=3, backend="threading")(delayed(func)(i) for i in range(3))
```

Comment: I tried your answer in the sample code and it serves the purpose. I just tried your answer in to my real program and it appears that the code becomes almost serial. No performance gain on parallelization, although the loops are embarrassingly parallel.

Comment: It is happening because of `GIL` in python. Same object update from different threads.